# Database connection error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

Whenver i go to locallhost/Blog/app/DB i encounter this error. I have tried so many times to connect to the database but could not connect. Even if i use my mysql password which is "root" this does not work.Please someone help me Here is my connection code:

```
host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password ="";
$db_name ="blog";

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die(' Database connection error '.$conn->connect_error);
}
```

This is my phpmyadmin user account:[image]

Comment: Maybe because you don't have a password set?

Comment: @Crimin4L I have a set password which is root. If I use this password in PHP code then I am seeing this error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Not sure it will make any difference, but have you tried setting the same password for `127.0.0.1`, `::1` and `localhost`? It seems odd to have different credentials for those since they are all local addresses. Could be worth a try? Or even just try with `127.0.0.1` instead. (And don't forget to flush privileges if you do any changes to the users)

Comment: Avoid using root. Create a new user with CRUD privilege and access to db

Answer (score 1):

As Indra said, avoid using `root`. This account should only be used by a human, even in a development environment. If you need an account that has complete and total access to everything, create one:

```
CREATE USER 'indra'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'indra'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The `root` account in MySQL should only be used when you are configuring replication or fixing something what went really, really wrong

Comment: 'indra'@'localhost' 